# Finding the index of the minimum value in a list of arrays with different length

Tags: arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a list with multiple arrays of different length:

```
L = [
  array([-10, -8, -3, 2, 1, 5, 12]),
  array([-9, -4, -1, 3, 5]),
  array([-11, -5, -4, 0, 1, 5, 7, 13, 18, 22])
]
```

How can I find the index of the lowest value the most efficiently?

For my example, the minimum value is -11 and the index is (2, 0), so the output should be (0, 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to do by using `concat` operation without any padding

```
#create the array indices
x = np.concatenate([np.repeat(i,array.shape[0]) for i, array in enumerate(L)]) 
#create the element indices
y = np.concatenate([np.arange(array.shape[0]) for array in L]) 

#concat the list to form a single array
concat = np.concatenate(L, axis=0)

x[concat.argmin()], y[concat.argmin()]    
#(2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, which needs preprocessing the list of arrays with padding, because of the unequal lengths of the arrays in `L`:

```
L = [
  np.array([-10, -8, -3, 2, 1, 5, 12]),
  np.array([-9, -4, -1, 3, 5]),
  np.array([-11, -5, -4, 0, 1, 5, 7, 13, 18, 22])
]

max_size = np.max([x.size for x in L])
max_value = np.max([np.max(x) for x in L])

L_padded = [np.pad(x, (0, max_size - x.size), 
                   constant_values= 1+max_value) for x in L]
L_2d = np.array(L_padded)

min_index = np.unravel_index(L_2d.argmin(), L_2d.shape)
(min_index[0], min_index[1])
```

---

Another way of doing the padding is by using [`pandas.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
L_2d = pd.DataFrame.from_records(L).fillna(0).values

min_index = np.unravel_index(L_2d.argmin(), L_2d.shape)
(min_index[0], min_index[1])
```

Comment: Any idea why it keeps generating different answers? Does it perform a random action somewhere?

Comment: I get always the same answer while running it for several times!

Comment: When padding, it places sometimes a very low or high number (or even NaN-values). Why is this? edit: when using '0' and 'constant', it doesn't do it.

Comment: Please, try with my new code.

Comment: @Steven01123581321: Please, see my edited answer, where I have added a much shorter solution.